# Connect to Mac remotely using iOS, BTMM address and a VNC client

Tags: ios, icloud, remote-desktop, back-to-my-mac

Which iOS app is able to connect to a Mac using its BTMM (Back to my Mac) address?

The address looks like this:

> your-imac.12345678.members.btmm.icloud.com

On a **Mac** using Screen Sharing.app, Apple Remote Desktop and Screens for Mac I can easily establish a connection.

With **iOS** using apps like iTeleport and Screens for iOS, however, I wasn't. All I get are connection errors.

Any helpful comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone can use the URL to connect. The connection is only successful when both parties in the connection are logged in to the same iCloud account. When you're accessing the URL on your Mac, you're logged in to iCloud so it works.

With iOS, I don't have experience trying to use a BTMM address there but I presume it is due to this. Try logging in to the same iCloud account on your iOS device, but if it doesn't work then it'll be because Apple don't expect you to be connecting over the BTMM address manually on iOS.

Comment: This is correct. Access to your BTMM address is limited by Apple, so that even if someone has your BTMM address, they probably cannot use it / connect to it unless they are also logged in to your iCloud account. I would not expect this to work with _any_ iOS apps. FWIW, I've had good luck with https://screensconnect.com/ if you use Screens, which is on both Mac and iOS.